# Angular JS-Update ng-repeat list after deleting element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Element delete works fine. Problem is that ng-repeat does not automatically updates itself. (I have to refresh the page to reflect changes.)

```
 <tr ng-repeat="error in filterErrors=(latestErrors
 | filter:{ Source:SearchSource} ) 
 | orderBy:predicate:reverse
 | filter:{ ErrorId:SearchErrorId,Application:SearchApplication} 
 | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize| limitTo: pageSize">

                <td ><input type="checkbox" ng-model="error.checked" ng-click="deletingIsReady()"/></td>
                <td >{{error.Host}}</td>
                <th >{{error.Type}}</th>
                <th >{{error.Source}}</th>

            </tr>
```

Service:

```
 errorReporter.factory('dataService', function ($http,$q) {


    var _deleteErrors = function (arrayOfErrors) {
        var deferred3 = $q.defer();
        var dataString = {
            arrayOfErrors: arrayOfErrors
        }

        $http.post(ROOT + 'Home/DeleteErrors', dataString, { cache: false }).
           then(function (data, status, headers, config) {
               deferred3.resolve();
           }, function () {
               deferred3.reject();
           });
        return deferred3.promise;

    }

return {
    getLatestErrors: _getLatestErrors,
    }
```

});

Controller function:

```
dataService.deleteErrors(arrayOfErrors).then(function () {
            var elementId=0;
            angular.forEach($scope.filterErrors, function (object) {
                elementId++;
                angular.forEach(arrayOfErrors, function (obj,index) {

                    if (object.ErrorId == obj)
                    {
                         console.log($scope.filterErrors.length);

                            $scope.filterErrors.splice(elementId, 1);

                        console.log($scope.filterErrors.length);

                    }
                })
            });
        })
```

Slicing works fine, I get in console.log ,for example 100,99 .Notice console logs few lines above, but anyway my ng-repeat doesn't update.

Comment: try using $scope.$apply()  after data changes

Comment: I tried. I get error $digest already in progress.

Comment: is there a reason you're passing back the (data.data) object in the deferred3.resolve, but you never pick it up in the controller? Your then(function(*) is empty

Comment: No, there is no reason. I delete that. Everything seemd good, ajax is working, splicing is working, but ng-repeat does not update inside temmplate.

Comment: Also, if I console.log  $scope.filterErrors I get good result, but for some reason it is not updated inside template.

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the JavaScript length property to equal 1 less than it was previously and it should update. For example, if you are repeating over an array with 5 keys (whether they be strings or objects), after you have deleted one of them, set the array length to 4.

```
var array = [
    {value: 'value1', label: 'Value 1'},
    {value: 'value2', label: 'Value 2'},
    {value: 'value3', label: 'Value 3'},
    {value: 'value4', label: 'Value 4'},
    {value: 'value5', label: 'Value 5'}
];   
var originalLength = array.length; // will equal 5

// Loop through and delete value3:
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i].value === 'value3') {
        delete array[i];
    }
}

// Reset the array length manually:
array.length = originalLength - 1;
```

The DOM with your ng-repeat should update.